# SonaQube5.0: Unable to start SonarQube on windows 7 64bit with Java 8

Tags: mysql, java-8, windows-7-x64, sonarqube

we are trying to run `SonarQube 5.0` at windows 7 64bit. we are using `MySQL` database and also change the setting according to the db credentials.  When we run the `StartSonar.bat` file under `\bin\windows-x86-64` directory there is no error produce and command window automatically close with some instructions. Please check the screen shot of command window. 
[image: **Screen Shot**]. Thanks in advance.

Exception in sonar.logs file.

```
2015.01.22 16:46:37 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]]  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:115) ~[sonar-core-5.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:73) ~[sonar-core-5.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
```

`sonar.properties` file configuration as below:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=root
sonar.jdbc.password=
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

`wrapper.conf` file changes as below

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java
```

Comment: Please post relevant contents of ``\logs\sonar.log``